# How to backup in recovery mode

Tags: itunes, recovery, data-transfer, data-recovery

How can I backup my iphone from this screen?
It got wet a couple weeks ago and it has not been working ever since, it doesn't turn on and apple said they can't repair it. I've tried updating it using itunes on my windows computer but it didn't work. All I want is to backup my files so I can buy a new one and not lose all my photos and files (I don't have Icloud)

Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How to backup in recovery mode

#### Unfortunately it’s not possible.

Recovery Mode on your iPhone is a way to either factory reset a device that is locked or restore from a previous backup. It is not designed to ge a way to backup files not previously backed up after a catastrophic event.

You can attempt to upgrade the OS and maybe gain access to your files, but failing that you might want to seek out the services of an independent repair shop that specializes in iPhone/iPad data recovery.

Once recovered, start a regimented habit of backing up your phone

Comment: Thank you! Updating didn't work. Does that mean there's really no way for me to get access to my data anymore?

Comment: Try the repair shop.  IPad Rehab is a highly rated shop and I belive they don’t charge you if they can’t get your data back.

Comment: I'm from brazil and unfortunally we don't have many places like that here =(
The only one I found is a two hour drive away and they carge 800 brazilian reais for the job. Using minimum wages as a reference that would be something like 700 US dollars.
Is this a fair price? I have no ideia about prices for this kind of stuff. Thank you!!

Comment: It’s probably cheaper to ship it to the US.  It should be [around $300USD for data recovery](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yXjAec4TBt29J7rdQqvazm2ORPMzOJdRTvfWJ0S0oko/preview).  If the phone is dead, you just need them to post your data to a cloud drive for download; you won’t have to ship the phone back.  The question is, hiw valuable is the data/photos to you?  That will determine if the price is too high.

Comment: Thank you so much!!